# addClass can't work

Tags: jquery, html, css

Recently,the script success with add in different content by changing different `data('type')` in html, but `"addClass"` function cant work, me want to make when my `data('type')=c1`,then it will `addClass('red')`, and when `data-type=c2`, it `addClass('green')`.

Is it have something wrong ? my html here,

```
<div class="box" data-type="c1">
   <div class="cm-cp-title">c1 title</div>
</div>


var cp = $('div.box');
    if (cp.data('type') == "c1") 
    {
        $(this).addClass('red');
        $('.box').append('<div class="cm-cp-title">' + 'c1 title' + '</div>');
    } 
    // if data-type == "c2"
    else if (cp.data('type') == "c2") 
    {
        $(this).addClass('green');
        $('.box').append('<div class="cm-cp-title">'+ 'c2 title' + '</div>');
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

*Besides,is it possible when hasClass('red'),then can put in .css({"background": "red"})?

Comment: `my html here,`->Where? I am unable to see. Also it's unclear what you exactly trying to do and what problem you are facing right now

Comment: You are trying to add the class "red" to $(this). What is "this" in your context? You must understand, "this" is always different according to your function. please post the full code in a js fiddle or here on Stack Overflow so we can help debuging. btw you could also use $(".classname").addClass("test") if you have a certain element.

Comment: problem solve,thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using "this" where you should use "cp":

```js
    var cp = $('div.box');
    if (cp.data('type') == "c1") 
    {
        cp.addClass('red');
        $('.box').append('<div class="cm-cp-title">' + 'c1 title' + '</div>');
    } 
    // if data-type == "c2"
    else if (cp.data('type') == "c2") 
    {
        cp.addClass('green');
        $('.box').append('<div class="cm-cp-title">'+ 'c2 title' + '</div>');
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: ic! ya, i just found it shouldn't put $(this) ,big thanks!